# Setting Timeout for network calls for Mobile App

Tags: codenameone

I have following questions regarding setting timeout in codenameone. please advise.

1. I see message retry/ cancel on the App when Mobile App trying hard to connect to internet or switching between Wifi/ Carrier networks. I have set the failsilently() for all the addToQueueandWait() requests. Still I see this error message on dialog. Is there a way I can set the timeout or other option for user to not show dialog ( User keep hitting retry and nothing works until the network connects ). How can I handle this situation.
2. Is setting Timeout is better option in this scenario? If yes, setting for request is better than setting it for NetworkManager?
3. What would be ideal timeout for Android and IOS devices as most of users have 1 min to 5 min as the time to lock the phone screen.
4. Does setting Timeout only works to establish the  server connection or will it work for slow response time from the server (20 ms takes 1500 ms sometimes). Login process of the App taking time when device having problems to connect to internet and it includes 7-8 network calls.Is it better to set the timeout at request level or network level for this case?
5. What kind of error messages can be thrown by timeout and that can used for both slow connection/ No connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that handles the `failSilently` flag. As you can see if `failSilently` is defined the method will return. So either you didn't define `failSilently` to true or some other part of the code set it to false. Or you have a network error listener that shows that dialog:

```
protected void handleException(Exception err) {
    if(exceptionListeners != null) {
        if(!isKilled()) {
            NetworkEvent n = new NetworkEvent(this, err);
            exceptionListeners.fireActionEvent(n);
        }
        return;
    }
    if(killed || failSilently) {
        failureException = err;
        return;
    }
    Log.e(err);
    if(silentRetryCount > 0) {
        silentRetryCount--;
        NetworkManager.getInstance().resetAPN();
        retry();
        return;
    }
    if(Display.isInitialized() && !Display.getInstance().isMinimized() &&
            Dialog.show("Exception", err.toString() + ": for URL " + url + "\n" + err.getMessage(), "Retry", "Cancel")) {
        retry();
    } else {
        retrying = false;
        killed = true;
    }
}
```

Timeout happens on the connection stage, once connected timeout doesn't apply. You would need to explicitly kill the connection. So `3` is probably irrelevant.

Timeout behaves inconsistently between platforms, generally I suggest using an error listener and instead of relying on the error result use that code to test the connectivity.

Comment: Thank You Shai. Probelm is I was not able to reproduce thsi issue on simualtor and it happens on Device. Is there a way to debug the problem as I already verified all the requests set to FailSilently()

Comment: Is there a way to check for slow response time from server and show message like "connection is slow or try later" . Please advise.

Comment: You can use an IO listener on a stream to detect slowness. The only solution for these issues is logging and in rare cases on device debugging https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-debug-on-an-android-device.html